# htaccess redirect from /folder/subforlder/some_url.html?param=var:some_alias to /somealias

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I htaccess redirect

from:

/folder/subforlder/some_url.html?param=var:some_alias

to:

/somealias

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=var:([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^folder/subfolder/some_url\.html$ /%1? [L,R]
```

You can change the `R` to `R=301` if you want a permanent redirect.